# Batch Script to check first 5 char vs MM-DD

Tags: date, batch-file, compare

I'm trying to build a script for one of our remote media players and am trying to get it to update once a file shows up in the dropbox. I need it to check the first 5 of the title against MM-DD and if they match then play the video in question. Playing the video is no issue, neither are the archives. My issue right now is that when I try to make a for loop for the files in the location I'm getting the syntax of the command is incorrect or "x" was not expected at this time. also, my date is being formatted like this: 05      -02, and I dont know why.

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Get Date :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
    Set _mm=00%%J
    Set _dd=00%%G
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros    
Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%   
Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%

::Finalize Date
Set date=%_mm%-%_dd%

echo %date%


::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Check the downloads folder for completed video files :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: Loop through all files

:loop

for %%a IN ("dir \Dropbox\Trailer") DO (


::IF the name is not blank, get the first 5 characters of the video name
set first5=%a:~0,5%

::Compare those characters to the date
IF "%first5%" == "%date%" (

    taskkill /im wmplayer.exe /t

::::::::::::::: Archive all previous Videos :::::::::::::

    for /r %%i in ("dir \Dropbox\Trailer") do (
        xcopy /s (%%i) "dir \Archived_Shows\"
    )

    ping localhost

    "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "C:\Dropbox\Trailer\%%a" /fullscreen

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Exit if new video is running ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    exit
    )
)

goto :loop
```

Comment: Easier to extract the date and time if you need it zero filled by doing this: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%G"`.  Then you can use your substrings to get the day and month.  The `dt` variable will be set to `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`

Comment: Don't set a variable named `%date%`, _the system already has a `%DATE%` and stealing it could result in a heavy sentence_.

Comment: The line `Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%   ` contains trailing spaces which cause your unwanted format. Use `Set "_mm=%_mm:~-2%"` to avoid that... And what is `dir \Dropbox\Trailer`? is there really a directory `dir ` with a trailing space? I don't think so; or is it just the `dir` command used at a wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable `%date%`, which is a system dynamic variable. Attempting to modify the contents is an unrecommended act, so instead, use another name.

Also, I have simplified the get-and-trim MM-DD part, and it works properly for me.

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
    Set _mm=00%%~J
    Set _dd=00%%~G
)
:s_done

::Finalize Date
Set titleDate=%_mm:~-2%-%_dd:~-2%
echo %titleDate%
pause
```

Comment: It's not particularly dangerous. The predefined meaning just no longer works. If they never use `%DATE%` in that batch file (or that `cmd` session), there's no consequence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your script is supposed to be doing but here is an example based on my understanding.

```bat
@Echo Off
CD "Dropbox\Trailer" 2>Nul || Exit /B

For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%A In (
    'WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^|FindStr [1-9]'
) Do Set /A _dd=10%%A,_MM=10%%B
Set "DString=%_MM:~-2%-%_dd:~-2%"

:Loop
If Not Exist "%DString%*" (
    Timeout 300 /NoBreak
    GoTo Loop
)

TaskKill /IM WMPlayer.exe /T 2>Nul

Timeout 10 /NoBreak >Nul

XCopy "." "%~dp0Archived_Shows" /S /D /I

For %%A In ("%DString%*") Do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "%%A" /FullScreen
)

GoTo Loop
```

If no matching file is found it currently checks for new ones every `300` seconds, *(5 minutes)*. If a matching file is found, the loop only resumes once you close `WMPlayer`. *You can change that timespan on line `11` as per your preference.*